# how to add input value to counter value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a counter that can respond to input values and add it to displayed count but continue to count by 1. The count starts at 0. I have the counter working with buttons, but not with the added input.

```js
let decreaseBtn = document.getElementById("buttonDecrease");
let increaseBtn = document.getElementById("buttonIncrease");
let counter = document.getElementById("counter");
let inputValue = document.getElementById("quantity").inputValue
let count = 0;

decreaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count--;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  counterStyle();
});

increaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count++;
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  counterStyle();
});

function counterStyle() {
  if (count < 0) {
    counter.classList.add("negative");
  } else if (count > 0) {
    counter.classList.add("positive");
  } else {
    counter.classList.remove("negative");
    counter.classList.remove("positive");
  }
}

function addInput() {
  console.log(inputValue)
}
addInput();
```

```html
<h1 id="counter">0</h1>
<div id="button__wrapper">
  <button id="buttonDecrease">-</button>
  <input type="text" id="quantity" value="1">
  <button id="buttonIncrease">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The property is `value`, not `inputValue`.

Comment: If you only grab the value of that input once, you can't change and then use that changed value later.

Answer (score 2):

Yuo need to get the value of the input in your event listener functions, not when the script starts. Then use that instead of just incrementing and decrementing.

The property to get the value of an input is `.value`, not `.inputValue`.

```js
let decreaseBtn = document.getElementById("buttonDecrease");
let increaseBtn = document.getElementById("buttonIncrease");
let counter = document.getElementById("counter");
let quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");
let count = 0;

decreaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count -= addInput();
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  counterStyle();
});

increaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count += addInput();
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  counterStyle();
});

function counterStyle() {
  if (count < 0) {
    counter.classList.add("negative");
    counter.classList.remove("positive");
  } else if (count > 0) {
    counter.classList.add("positive");
    counter.classList.remove("negative");
  } else {
    counter.classList.remove("negative");
    counter.classList.remove("positive");
  }
}

function addInput() {
  return parseInt(quantity.value);
}
```

```css
.positive {
  background-color: green;
}

.negative {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="counter">0</h1>
<div id="button__wrapper">
  <button id="buttonDecrease">-</button>
  <input type="text" id="quantity" value="1">
  <button id="buttonIncrease">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have [**`increment`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment) and [**`decrement`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement) operators when you handle the click event.  This is why it is always just adding or subtracting by 1, and not by the value of the input.  You should be adding the value of the input element, after using [**`parseInt()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to make it into an add-able integer.

Your code that I'm changing:

```
count--;
```

What I'm changing it to...

```
count -= parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);
```

And I'm doing the same for `count++`.

***In addition***, it seems your `counterStyles()` function isn't removing classes appropriately, and sometimes you'll have a red background with positive integers.  I fixed this up by adding the needed `removeClass()` calls here.

The rest of the code is the same...

```js
let decreaseBtn = document.getElementById("buttonDecrease");
let increaseBtn = document.getElementById("buttonIncrease");
let counter = document.getElementById("counter");
let inputValue = document.getElementById("quantity").inputValue
let count = 0;

decreaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count -= parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  counterStyle();
});

increaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  count += parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value, 10);
  counter.innerHTML = count;
  counterStyle();
});

function counterStyle() {
  if (count < 0) {
    counter.classList.add("negative");
    counter.classList.remove("positive");
  } else if (count > 0) {
    counter.classList.add("positive");
    counter.classList.remove("negative");
  } else {
    counter.classList.remove("negative");
    counter.classList.remove("positive");
  }
}

function addInput() {
  console.log(inputValue)
}
addInput();
```

```css
.positive {
  background-color: green;
}

.negative {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="counter">0</h1>
<div id="button__wrapper">
  <button id="buttonDecrease">-</button>
  <input type="text" id="quantity" value="1">
  <button id="buttonIncrease">+</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, zfin!  Since it starts out with `value=1`, it seems to work in doing that automatically already?  No need to have special cases, it'll still keep working just as before.  It'll use the "1" value it starts out with, and just do the incrementing naturally, because it's increasing/decreasing by just 1. =)

Comment: @zfin: I just updated my answer with the new styles, so it should look better now, and added some small improvements.  Don't forget, it's always nice here to mark an answer as correct, if it helped you out, so that it can help others out!